# Check reviews in App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, review

I wanted to know if is possible check a user leaves a review on App store ... maybe to unlock some function of the app.
I've seen appirater but does not include this feature, any ideas on how to make.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can *suggest* to your users that they rate or review your application, but that's it.